# add cucumber plugin into intellij idea

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, testng

I want to add add cucumber plugin into intellij idea .I have did this using eclips.

```
 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/Feature"
        ,glue={"src/main/stepDefinition"}
        )
 
public class TestRunner {
```

Comment: file -> settings -> plugins -> 'Cucumber for Java'. Normally you should be able to use all annotations, and IntelliJ will recognize the file-extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add from IDE go to settings -->plugins then search **cucumber-java** click ok and you need to restart IDE

Answer (score 4):

In IntelliJ, go to file -> settings -> plugins -> choose the plugin `Cucumber for Java`

Normally you should be able to use all annotations and IntelliJ will recognize the file-extensions